# How can I preload a Python library in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-views, libraries

Within one of my Django apps, I have code that looks like this within views.py:

```
import myLib

resultOne = myLib.myFunction('Some data')
resultTwo = myLib.myFunction('Some more data')
resultThree = myLib.myFunction('Even more data')
```

Whenever I visit the page, it takes a good minute to load. The reason is that `myLib` takes up a lot of memory and it is loading each time the page is loaded. I know that `resultTwo` and `resultThree` will execute quickly after `resultOne` has executed.

I want to preload `myLib` in Django so that it is stored in memory and so `resultOne`, `resultTwo`, and `resultThree` all execute quickly. How can I do this?

**EDIT:**
This may fall under the category of caching. The input that `resultOne`, `resultTwo`, and `resultThree` changes each time and they are run very often.

Comment: How often do you need to execute resultOne, resultTwo, and resultThree?

Comment: Very often. Assume that they need to be executed every time that the page is loaded.

Comment: The library import isn't the problem.  It's performed once during the first page load.  The time is eaten up in your calls to `myFunction`, so you should examine that code.

Comment: I'm not sure if the library import is the problem or not. But, I do not believe the problem is with `myFunction`. Remember, `resultTwo` and `resultThree` execute quickly. I know this because I placed print statements in between all of them and while they all take 30 seconds to appear, they appear all at the same time.

Comment: You keep leaving `resultOne` out of your mentions of fast executing results - is `resultOne` the slow one?

Comment: I apologize. `resultOne` is always the slow one regardless of the input. In fact, I could give the same input as `resultTwo` and `resultThree` and it will still take the longest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django, you can import it in `__init__.py` and access it as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If what takes time is the loading/processing of data, you should look into Django's [caching framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/), which uses [memcached](http://memcached.org) to store frequently used data in a separate process.

Comment: I have been looking at it, however I still cannot find anything on how to cache a library. The data that `resultOne`, `resultTwo`, and `resultThree` take always changes.